# Magento Category id array on attribute

Tags: php, magento

I have a site running on Magento and i have build some hand made code onto the view.phtml and list.phtml

```
<?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();?>
<?php if($category->getId()==80): ?>
    Command what to do
<?php else: ?>
    Else command this
<?php endif; ?>
```

What i would like to make is to check more categories ( like eg. 80,81 ) before echo it. 
How do i have to change the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array)

```
<?php if(in_array($category->getId(), array(80, 81, ...))): ?>
```

If you want different code for the various categories:

```
<?php if($category->getId()==80): ?>
    ...
<?php elseif($category->getId()==81): ?>
    ...
```